# Don't enter in VBA macro when editing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a drop down list column in an Excel worksheet to select a category. I have created a macro who replace the selected value by its ID after category selection (Worksheet_Change event). 
Users have to fill the worksheet with ID but thank to this function, they just have to select a category in the drop down list and the ID replace the user choice.

It work well but I have a problem: if the user wants to write directly the ID in the cell, I have an error (Invalid value) and the macro is disabled.

How to do the difference in the Worksheet_Change between a change by the drop down list and a change by writing ? Or is there an other solution ?

Thank you !

Comment: The probleme is not on the macro, I need users can write in drop down list without trigger an error

Comment: what is this "drop down list column"? never heard of such, sorry.

Comment: Are you using Data Validation as your dropdown?

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky: it's combo box

Comment: @user3561813: yes I use it

Comment: so, the dropdown box is not something you embedded into the worksheet but, in fact, is the Excel-presented dropdown from the Data Validation applied the cell(s). Is this correst?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you ARE using Data Validation:

Data Validation allows the user to optionally trigger an Error message if an incorrect value is entered (This error is the default setting). If you want to allow users to input information NOT in the list, turn off the error message by doing the following:

In the Data Validation dialog box, you will notice there are actually 3 tabs: `Settings`, `Input Message`, and `Error Alert`. Select the `Error Alert` tab, then UNCHECK `Show Error Alert after invalid data is entered`.

Does this resolve the problem?

Comment: This solution resolve the problem (with macro modification).
Thank you !